# Return HTTP Error 401 Code & Skip Filter Chains

Tags: spring-security

Using a custom Spring Security filter, I'd like to return an HTTP 401 error code if the HTTP Header doesn't contain a particular key-value pair.

Example:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

   HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
   final String val = request.getHeader(FOO_TOKEN)

   if(val == null || !val.equals("FOO")) {
       // token is not valid, return an HTTP 401 error code
       ...
   }
   else {
    // token is good, let it proceed
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
   }
```

As I understand, I could do the following:

(1) `((HttpServletResponse) res).setStatus(401)` and skip the remaining filter chain

OR

(2) throw an exception that, eventually, results in Spring Security throwing a 401 error to the client.

If #1 is the better option, how can I skip the filter chain after calling `setStatus(401)` on the response?

Or, if #2 is the right way to go, which exception should I throw?

Comment: If you return from the method after `setStatus` that stops further processing of the request. The filter chain only proceeds if you call `chain.doFilter`.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'll try that. Post as answer? Also can you please post a reference so I can read more?

Comment: You might want to implement an AuthenticationEntryPoint like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767267/handle-spring-security-authentication-exceptions-with-exceptionhandler

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the [API docs for the `doFilter` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain%29), you can:

- **Either** invoke the next entity in the chain using the FilterChain object (chain.doFilter()),
- **or** not pass on the request/response pair to the next entity in the filter chain to block the request processing

so setting the response status code and returning immediately without invoking `chain.doFilter` is the best option for what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 51):

I suggest this solution below.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final String val = request.getHeader(FOO_TOKEN)

        if (val == null || !val.equals("FOO")) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "The token is not valid.");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works but it gives this error in the logs `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed`.

Answer (score 6):

Just do as they say in the upper answer. "so setting the response status code and returning immediately"
This is just type:

```
res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
return;
```

Answer (score 5):

So you can use something like this.

```
@Override
public void doFilter() {
    if (whiteListOrigins.contains(incomeOrigin)) {
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", incomeOrigin);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Not Allowed to Access. Please try with valid Origin.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives this error  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. Since I implemented OAuth2, I cannot return all errors as response to the Client. Some exceptions are difficult to catch.

```
res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
return;
```

This was the only solution working for me so far.

I have to use it on MalformedJwtException and SignatureException, because if I use response.sendError() , it does not work and calling it a second time throws another error.

Comment: In fact, the answer was incomplete.
      response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
      return;
this should be it