# Custom validation logic for parameter in REST endpoint Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, spring-rest

I currently have this `RequestMapping` where I use validation through a regular expression:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/example/{id}", method = GET)
 public Response getExample(
         @PathVariable("id") String id,
         @RequestParam(value = "myParam", required = true) @Valid @Pattern(regexp = MY_REGEX) String myParamRequest,
         @RequestParam(value = "callback", required = false) String callback,
         @RequestHeader(value = "X-API-Key", required = true) @Valid @Pattern(regexp = SEGMENTS_REGEX) String apiKeyHeader) {

     // Stuff here...
 }
```

However, the regulare expression is not enough. Instead, I would like to do some custom validation on the header attribute i.e.

```
if (!API_KEY_LIST.contains(apiKeyHeader)) {
    throw Exception();
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @RequestHeader(value = "X-API-Key", required = true) @Valid @Pattern(regexp = SEGMENTS_REGEX) String apiKeyHeader

Can you please let me know is the above line works for you?

Comment: There is aleardy a feature request Spring backlog, checkout https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380. However, i was able to achieve what you are trying using `@Validated` annotation on Controller.

Comment: Note that while [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11041) is not resolved, validation annotations on `@PathVariable`, `@RequestHeader`, and `@RequestParam` only work if the class is annotated with `@Validated`. Just in case someone wonders why `@Pattern` works for the OP...

Comment: could you please share some example about @Validated & validate headers?

Answer (score 9):

Best way to do this IMO is to create a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that would look something like this using a custom annotation `@Segment`:

```
public class SegmentHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(String.class)
            && parameter.getParameterAnnotation(Segment.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        String apiKey = webRequest.getHeader("X-API-Key");
        if (apiKey != null) {
            if (!API_KEY_LIST.contains(apiKey)) {
                throw new InvalidApiKeyException();
            }
            return apiKey;
        } else {
            return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your controller signature looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/{id}", method = GET)
 public Response getExample(
         @PathVariable("id") String id,
         @RequestParam(value = "myParam", required = true) @Valid @Pattern(regexp = MY_REGEX) String myParamRequest,
         @RequestParam(value = "callback", required = false) String callback,
         @Segment String apiKeyHeader) {

     // Stuff here...
 }
```

You'll register the handler method argument resolver in you WebMvcConfigurationAdapter:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(segmentHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    public SegmentHandlerMethodArgumentResolver segmentHandler() {
        return new SegmentHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    }

}
```

Comment: why this is named 'Segment'?

Comment: parameter.getParameterAnnotation(Segment.class); should be parameter.getParameterAnnotation(Segment.class) != null

Answer (score 3):

There is aleardy a feature request Spring backlog, checkout [JIRA](http://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380). However, i was able to achieve what you are trying using `@Validated` annotation on Controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@Validated
public class UserController {

   @GetMapping("/{loginId}")
   public User getUserBy(@PathVariable @LoginID final String loginId) {
      // return some user
   }
}
```

Here `@LoginID` is custom validator. And `@Validated` is from `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` which does the trick.

Comment: can u share your solution please?

Comment: could you please share the @LoginID implementation?

Comment: Just implement a hibernate custom validator, checkout this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html

Answer (score 1):

**1) Check manually**

You can inject the HttpServletRequest and check the headers.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(HttpServletRequest request){
        if(request.getHeader("apiKeyHeader") == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**2) Inject the header**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestHeader(value="myheader") String myheader){
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

That will return:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1469805110889,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException",
  "message": "Missing request header 'myheader' for method parameter of type String",
  "path": "/test"
}
```

if the header is missing.

**3) Use filter**

You can automate the check with some filter if you want to use it on multiple methods. In your custom filter just get the header(like in method 1) and if the header is missing just respond with 400 or whatever you want. For me that makes sense when you don't use the header value in the controller method and only need to validate that it's present.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() { 
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(apiHeaderFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/example/*");
    registration.setName("apiHeaderFilter");
    registration.setOrder(1);
    return registration;
} 

@Bean(name = "ApiHeaderFilter")
public Filter apiHeaderFilter() {
    return new ApiHeaderFilter();
}
```

**Skip the request**

If you use headers attribute in @RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
```

this will result in 404 if there ain't no other handler to take the request.

Comment: For option #3: how would we use this filter code to return a bad request response if the header was not sent properly?

Comment: @IcedDante See the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621037/return-http-error-401-code-skip-filter-chains

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following class.
Do any validations inside "doFilter" method and set appropriate response code.

```
@Configuration
public class ApiHeaderFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;
        String token = request.getHeader("token");
        if (StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(token)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
    }
}
```