# Send SC_UNAUTHORIZED for an authenticated request

Tags: servlets, spring-security, filter, http-response-codes

I want to put some additional checks (in a filter) to some parameters after the request is authenticated by Spring and based on those checks want to allow or block the login. If the checks fails then I want to send a 401 in response instead of 200 which spring sends. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621037/return-http-error-401-code-skip-filter-chains