# No more than 5 users or processes can concurrently access a method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Have a web application and I want no more than 5 users or processes can access a particular method concurrently. My approach is having a counter when each call to the method increases the counter and decreasing the counter while exiting the method which is bit dirty and I dont this is efficient or for that matter using threads. Is there any efficient way of doing that.

Comment: What method? What processes? This question is really vague and doesn't make a lot of sense. How would one process know if another process is accessing a method?

Comment: Take it as a simple method in a spring controller when can be accessed by making a get call to that end point.

Comment: If there's multiple processes this is a lot harder.

Comment: Sounds like the static counter has to exist somewhere - what about as a filter for that specific endpoint?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621037/return-http-error-401-code-skip-filter-chains) might work, but set status to something like HTTP 423.

Answer (score 0):

Use a semaphore with size 5. At max only five process can access your code and 6th thread will be put on hold. For detail read this block [https://dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-semaphores ]

Comment: This won't work if there's multiple processes involved, only multiple *threads*.