# How to redirect to a custom page on @PreAuthorize error?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-annotations

I want to redirect to a custom html page on an `@PreAuthorize` authentication error?

I have used `@PreAuthorize("hasRole("Admin"))` for a controller. So if the user doesn't have the Admin role he will be kicked out and I am seeing authentication error.

But I want to override this authentication failure error and redirect the user to standard error page I developed.

Is there a solution for it ?

Code:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole("Admin")){
public List<Object> getBooksList(String id){
    return bookList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to notice is that the [`@PreAuthorize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreAuthorize.html) annotation is linked to an [`AuthenticationManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html) which can be set with the [`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.html).

You can catch authentication exception with a [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotated class but you have to register a new [`AuthenticationEntryPoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html).

Here is how : [Handle spring security authentication exceptions with @ExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767267/handle-spring-security-authentication-exceptions-with-exceptionhandler)