# How to handle UsernameNotFoundException spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-security

How to handle `UsernameNotFoundException` ?

In spring security when username not found the `UserDetailsService` implementation throws a `UsernameNotFoundException`. For example like this:

```
   @Override
   @Transactional
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       logger.info("Load user by username: {}", username);
       User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username).orElseThrow(
                   () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with -> username or email: " + username));

       return UserPrinciple.build(user);
   }
```

I would like to build a custom "User not found REST response".
How should I catch/handle this exception? I have implemented a handler method in the  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation the handler:

```
  private static void handleException(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp, AuthenticationException e)
           throws IOException {
       PrintWriter writer = rsp.getWriter();
       writer.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new AuthResponse("", null, null, null, null,
               "Authentication failed.", false)));
       rsp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
   }
```

But this method should wait for an  `AuthenticationException` exception which, and during runtime the type of the exception is `java.lang.NullPointerException` so I'm not able to cast or retrieve the the initial `UsernameNotFoundException`.

Any advice would be appreciated. 
Many many regards :).

Comment: have a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Security layer comes before anything in the controllers and `@ControllerAdvice`. 
Hence `@ControllerAdvice` isn't an option since `UsernameNotFoundException` which is a subclass of `AuthenticationException` is thrown during authenticaton, making your exception handlers in `@ControllerAdvice` unreachable.

You can only use `@ControllerAdvice` and `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` if you are throwing `UsernameNotFoundException` inside controller or any others beans referenced from the controllers.

Here is my suggestion - that you implement `AuthenticationFailureHandler` and use it with `AuthenticationFilter` that you are using for your security configuration.
Spring boot security comes with about 4 handler interfaces for security related issues

1. `AccessDeniedHandler` - this handles issues like when a user not having required roles.
2. `AuthenticationEntryPoint` - this handles issues like when a user tries to access a resource without appropriate authentication elements.
3. `AuthenticationFailureHandler` - this handles issues like when a user is not found(i.e.  `UsernameNotFoundException`) or other exceptions thrown inside authentication provider. In fact, this handles other authentication exceptions that are not handled by `AccessDeniedException` and `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.
4. `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` - this helps to do stuff like redirection after a user is successfully authenticated.

See the following example snippets for the implementation of all the 4 interfaces. Please customize these to your taste.

1. `AccessDeniedHandler` implementation

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

@Component
public class RestAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Map<String,Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("status","34");
        response.put("message","unauthorized api access");

        //httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        OutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(out,response);
        //mapper.writeValue(out, response);

        out.flush();
    }
}
```

2. `AuthenticationEntryPoint` Implementation

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

@Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Map<String,Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("status","34");
        response.put("message","unauthorized access");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        OutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(out, response);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

3. `AuthenticationFailureHandler` implementation

```
package com.ibiller.webservices.security;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;


@Component
public class RestAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                        AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException
    {

        Map<String,Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("status","34");
        response.put("message","unauthorized access");

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        OutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(out, response);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

4. `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` implementation

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class RestSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        Set<String> roles = 
          AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            //do something
        }

    }
}
```

This is the Security configuration that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that connects everything together.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/**"),new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")
    );

    AuthenticationProvider provider;

    public SecurityConfiguration(final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        super();
        this.provider=authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/info/**");//url that will be ignored
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
               .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v1/**").hasRole("API")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("SUPER_ADMIN","ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
      AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    RestAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new RestAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    RestAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler(){
        return new RestAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    RestSuccessHandler successHandler(){
        return new RestSuccessHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be updated? Currently, the constructor you are using to set up `AuthenticationFilter` object is obsolete in the current Spring Security version. Right now, the new constructor is `AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager, AuthenticationConverter)` constructor. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFilter.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure of your project, but a usual solution in this case is using `@ControllerAdvice` mechanism (separated class or in controller):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = UsernameNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handle(final UsernameNotFoundException exception) {
        ...//set headers, response attributes and response body
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try to implement it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the class that inherits from  `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` you have to override the method `unsuccessfulAuthentication`
It calls the super class method, but what it does it's it redirects to another context of error, which makes the Authorization filter activates.
Instead, just fill the request information as your client is expecting (Json in my case)

```
@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode message = mapper.createObjectNode();
    message.put("success", false);
    message.put("message", "Invalid credentials");
    String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(message);

    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("application/json");
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.print(json);
    out.flush();
}
```