# How to return different error message resolved by concrete derived AuthenticationException type in custom AuthenticationFailureHandler

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to construct my blog application's authentication/authorization. We've decided to use RESTful api, in order to return json message to the client while handling the authentication error in the server side, i have to write custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, like:

```java
public class RganAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RganAuthenticationFailureHandler.class);


    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("some description");
    }
}
```

The `AuthenticationException` have some concrete derived type, describe what's the exact error, like:
`UsernameNotFoundException`, `BadCredentialsException`, `AuthenticationServiceException`...

It seems to me that i should return different error message for different exception type. For example, for `UsernameNotFoundException` and `BadCredentialsException`, i might return "wrong username or password, for `AuthenticationServiceException`, i might return "some sth wrong happen during getting your credentials, please retry later" and a different HTTP status code(like 500).

Now here's the problem, i know i can write code like:

```java
if(e instanceof UsernameNotFoundException || e instanceof BadCredentialsException){
    httpServletResponse.getWriter.write("message1");
}else if(e instance of AuthenticationServiceException){
    httpServletResponse.getWriter.write("message2");
}else if(...){
    // ...
}
```

to handle this, but it seems not to be the best solution, i have to write a serie of `else if` block.

I've read some post like https://stackoverflow.com/a/46530064/8510613, it seems that use @ControllerAdvice and `HandlerExceptionResolver` is also not the best solution.

So how should i handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the decision further up the stack by using [DelegatingAuthenticationFailureHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/DelegatingAuthenticationFailureHandler.html)

> An AuthenticationFailureHandler that delegates to other
>   AuthenticationFailureHandler instances based upon the type of
>   AuthenticationException passed into onAuthenticationFailure

Comment: You mean like providing the ```<ExceptionClass, handler>``` map to the constructor of ```DelegatingAuthenticationFailureHandler``` and use it as my applications's ```failureHandler```?

Comment: I would think so

Comment: You could have at least added a code example for this.