# How to return custom error with many fields or responce entity after handling AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

everyone!
I making a defense against password brute force.
I successfully handle AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent when the user writes the right login and wrong password. But the problem is that I want to return JSON with two fields

```
{
message : '...' <- custom message 
code : 'login_failed' 
}
```

The problem is that it returns standart forbidden exception, but I need custom json.

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationAttemptsHandler {

  protected final MessageSource messageSource;
  private final AuthenticationAttemptsStore attemptsStore;
  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private final UserDetailsLockService userDetailsLockService;

@EventListener
  public void handleFailure(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
    val authentication = event.getAuthentication();
    val userDetails = findUserDetails(authentication.getName());
    userDetails.ifPresent(this::failAttempt);
}

private Optional<UserDetails> findUserDetails(String username) {
...
}

private void failAttempt(UserDetails details) {
  val username = details.getUsername();
  val attempt = attempt(loginAttemptsProperties.getResetFailuresInterval());
  int failures = attemptsStore.incrementFailures(username, attempt);
  if (failures >= 2) {
    Instant lockedUntil = Instant.now().plus(loginAttemptsProperties.getLockDuration());
    userDetailsLockService.lockUser(username, lockedUntil);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
    String date = formatter.format(lockedUntil);
    String message = String.format("Account will locked till %s", date);
    throw new SecurityException(message);
    //FailAttemptsExceptionResponse response = new FailAttemptsExceptionResponse(message, // 
    //"login_ failed");   <---- tryed return entity from this method. Does not work.
    // return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
   } else {
     String message = String.format("You have %s attempts.", (3 - failures));
     // FailAttemptsExceptionResponse response = new FailAttemptsExceptionResponse(message, 
     "login_ failed");
      throw new SecurityException(message);
      // return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
  }
}
```

RuntimeException returns 500 status? but I need forbidden

```
public class SecurityException extends RuntimeException {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
  public SecurityException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
  }
}
```

Responce model

```
public class FailAttemptsExceptionResponse {

  String message;
  String code;

  public FailAttemptsExceptionResponse(String message, String code) {
   super();
   this.message = message;
   this.code = code;
  }
  
 public String getMessage() {
   return message;
 }

 public String getCode() {
  return code;
 } 
}
```

Tried to handle SecurityException and then returns model? but it does not work

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SeurityAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(SecurityException.class)
public ResponseEntity<FailAttemptsExceptionResponse> handleNotFoundException(SecurityException ex) {
    FailAttemptsExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new FailAttemptsExceptionResponse(ex.getMessage(), 
  "login_ failed");
     return new ResponseEntity<FailAttemptsExceptionResponse>(exceptionResponse, 
  HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
  }
}
```

I successfully handle AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent, but how can I return JSON response model from the handler with a custom message?

Answer (score 0):

@ControllerAdvice
public class SeurityAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

```
    @ExceptionHandler(SecurityException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<FailAttemptsExceptionResponse> handleNotFoundException(SecurityException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
        FailAttemptsExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new FailAttemptsExceptionResponse(ex.getMessage(),
                "login_ failed");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        return new ResponseEntity<FailAttemptsExceptionResponse>(exceptionResponse,
                HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
}
```

1. maybe you need to add HttpServletResponse  and set the http status.

Answer (score 0):

Register the entry point
As mentioned, I do it with Java Config. I just show the relevant configuration here, there should be other configuration such as session stateless, etc.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomEntryPoint());
    }
}
```

U can create AuthenticationEntryPoint.

Короч тут почитай xD

[Handle spring security authentication exceptions with @ExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767267/handle-spring-security-authentication-exceptions-with-exceptionhandler)